# Can find all the prime numbers but doesn't include "2"?

Tags: java

It now can find all the prime numbers in the input range, but it can't find number 2, the smallest prime number.

```
for(int number=2;number<range;number++){
    for(int testDivide=2;testDivide<Math.sqrt(number);testDivide++){
        if(number%testDivide!=0) {
            System.out.println(number);
        }
        break;

    }
```

For range 10 it prints:
5
7
9
but no 2.

Comment: sqrt(2) ~= 1.414 which is smaller than 2 so the inner for loop doesn't execute.

Comment: 9 is not a prime number.

Comment: `9` isn't prime... and you're missing `3` aswell

Comment: A little too lazy mr frog :)

Comment: Primes are 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37....

Comment: @FDinoff - So what? 2 is prime. The problem is OP's logic: a number is prime if the loop completes without finding any even divisors. Instead, OP is printing the number if it finds any non-divisor.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code is not producing correct results (missing 2 and 3; including 9) is that your primality test logic is backwards. A number is prime if the inner loop completes without finding any even divisors; instead you are printing the number if you find any non-divisor.

Try this instead:

```
for( int number = 2; number < range; number++) {
    boolean divisible = false;
    int limit = (int) Math.sqrt(number);
    for (int testDivide = 2; !divisible && testDivide <= limit; testDivide++) {
        divisible = number % testDivide == 0;
    }
    if (!divisible) {
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

Note that a much more efficient way to generate all primes in a range is the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: @LazyFrog - Oops. It should have been `<= limit` in the inner loop, not `< limit`. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

check the code here:
package core;

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 2;; i++) {
            if (Priem(i)) {
                cnt++;
                System.out.println(i);
                if (cnt == 200)
                    break;
            }
        }

    }

    public static boolean Priem(int n) {
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The approach of find x amount of prime numbers is not a safe/smart approach as this will get extremely cpu intensive and blow out very quickly. I think going for find prime numbers in x range is a better approach.

Comment: Whay we need to go to check upto `n`.?? Checking upto `n/2` will also suffice.

Comment: Use this line for (int i = 2; i <Math.sqrt(n); i++)

Comment: The logic for going only up to sqrt(number) is that if a number is not prime, then at least one of the factors is less than sqrt(number).

Comment: Use still n/2 --for (int i = 2; i <n/2; i++)

Comment: Try this code, bit improved one; 

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int cnt = 0;
   
  for (int i = 2;; i++) {
   if(i==2){
    System.out.println(i);
    continue;
   }
   if (Priem(i)) {
    cnt++;
    System.out.println(i);
    if (cnt == 200)
     break;
   }
  }

 }

 public static boolean Priem(int n) {
  for (int i = 2; i <Math.sqrt(n)+1; i++) {
   if (n % i == 0) {
    return false;
   }
  }
  return true;
 }

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your for loop a little mixed up.

```
for(int testDivide=2;testDivide<Math.sqrt(number);testDivide++){

}
```

Not sure why you are stopping when testDivide is equal to sqrt(number), you should stop when testDivide is greater than.

Also inside your inner for loop isn't correct either:

```
    if(number%testDivide!=0) {
        System.out.println(number);
    }
    break;
```

Basically all this will do is check to see of the number is divisible by 2 and then break. You only need to break when you find a number which cleanly divides (number%testDivide==0). Maybe keep a boolean which you set to true when you break and only print after the inner for loop finishes if that boolean is false.

Something along the lines:

```
    for (int number=2; number<range; number++){
        boolean found = false;
        int limit = (int)Math.sqrt(number);
        for (int testDivide=2; testDivide<=limit; testDivide++){
            if(number%testDivide==0) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }   
        if (!found) System.out.println(number);
    }
```

Comment: The logic for going only up to sqrt(number) is that if a number is not prime, then at least one of the factors is less than sqrt(number).

Comment: I've heard of that "trick" but it doesn't seem valid until in this context. Do you have to round up the sqrt?

Comment: No, you do not have to round up. If any factor is greater than sqrt(n), then there is a factor less than sqrt(n) (just divide n by the factor greater than sqrt(n)). If sqrt(n) is an integer, then of course that may be the only factor. Prudence would dictate taking the floor of sqrt(n) + epsilon to guard against floating point errors (I don't know of Math.sqrt will find integer square roots exactly).

Comment: @TedHopp Is it up to and including the sqrt? I mean <=sqrt(num) or <sqrt(num)

Answer (score 0):

In your code when number is 2, `sqrt(2)` is 1.41 and control doesn't go into the loop. I didn't get the logic behind iterating upto `sqrt(number)`. Try this code

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int range = 500; //I assume
    for (int i = 2; i< range; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

}

public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= number/2; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        if(i % 2 == 1) {
            i++;  //If not divided by 2 then
                  // need not to check for any even number
                  // Essentially incrementing i twice hereafter
        }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: you never instantiated range

Comment: The logic for going only up to sqrt(number) is that if a number is not prime, then at least one of the factors is less than sqrt(number). The problem is not the loop limits; it's OP's logic. The number is prime if the loop completes with no integer evenly dividing the number. Instead, OP prints out the result if it finds _any_ non-divisor.

Comment: Your logic doesn't hold true for 2 as `sqrt(2)` is 1.44 which is less than 2 and hence your inner loop condition is false.

Comment: @VallabhPatade - The inner loop logic is completely flawed. The logic should be that if the inner loop exits without having found an exact divisor, then the number is prime. If the inner loop does not execute at all (as will be the case with 2 and 3), then 2 and 3 will be (correctly) classified as prime.

Comment: @TedHopp Can you please explain maybe a test case for which code will fail.?

Comment: Um, sorry about the wording of the last comment. I was referring to the inner loop of OP's code, not to any loop in your code. The comment was about why OP's inner loop did not need to enter at all (which will happen for number=2 or 3). As an aside: your loop in `isPrime` could stop after hitting sqrt(number); it's a waste to go past that since if number has a factor f > sqrt(number) then the loop would have already found (number/f) as a factor.

Answer (score 0):

Note that one of the best ways to generate a list of prime numbers is the "[Sieve of Erwhatshisface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)":

Create a list of consecutive integers starting with 2, up to the max number you'd like to search.  Take the first non-zero number in the list (2) and repeatedly step 2 from that location, zeroing out every 2nd list element.

Next take the second non-zero number (3) and repeatedly step 3 from that location, zeroing.  Continue with each non-zero value in the list, until you've processed all of them (or at least halfway through, at which point you'll be stepping beyond the end of the list).

The non-zero numbers remaining are all primes.

Answer (score 0):

Reposting code here as not fit in comments:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int cnt = 0;

        for (int i = 2;; i++) {
            if(i==2){
                System.out.println(i);
                continue;
            }
            if (Priem(i)) {
                cnt++;
                System.out.println(i);
                if (cnt == 200)
                    break;
            }
        }

    }

    public static boolean Priem(int n) {
        for (int i = 2; i <Math.sqrt(n)+1; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```